# RDP access to VM not possible unless WebConsole opened

Tags: windows-10, vmware, rdp, esxi

I have a VMware ESXI 7.0 installation with several VMs.

To all VM that run on Windows Server 2019 I can connect via RDP without any issue.

But for the VMs that run on Windows 10, the RDP connection fails. I always have to connect to the VM via Web Console (I don't have to login. It seems to be enough waiting at the login screen of Windows). Only then RDP connection is possible from my client.

So, I don't suspect a problem with RDP activation in Windows 10 itself. What else could be the issue?

Thanks

EDIT:
It might be related to VMware tools..?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, on windows server you get 2 remote connections + 1 local connection and on windows 10 you have only 1 allowed connection.

If you don't have any connexion on your windows 10 you should check on your VMs if users have the right to connect remotely, or your remote configuration settings.